# using the $.ajax function to fetch a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm learning how to use jQuery methods of making AJAX calls, at the moment what I would like to know is how I use the `$.ajax` function to return a certain elements content. I realize this can be done easily enough using `.load()` but would like to get the results using `.ajax()`. At the moment I am fetching the clicked href attribute and returning the whole pages data when I would like to just return the `#container` content of the page?

Sample code being used:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    /* Ajax load in portfolio pages */
    var ajaxLoader = $('#ajax-loader');
    var folioContainer = $('#folio-container');

    ajaxLoader.hide();

    $('div.wp-pagenavi a', 'div#content').click(function(e) {

        $.ajax({
            url : this.href,
            method : 'get',
            success : function(data){
                folioContainer.html(data);
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

Comment: Why do people do this: `var href = $(this).attr('href'); ` when `var href = this.href` is more compact and faster?  jQuery should be used for things that it's better at, not things it's worse at.  Or, even better just replace `url: href` with `url: this.href` and skip the intermediate variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to `.filter()` the response from the server to select only the data you want:

```
        success : function(data){
            folioContainer.html($(data).filter('#container'));
        }
```

Here's a jsfiddle of this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/5HSzB/

Here's an optimized version of your code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    /* Ajax load in portfolio pages */
    var ajaxLoader = $('#ajax-loader').hide();

    $('.wp-pagenavi', '#content').find('a').click(function(e) {       

        $.ajax({
            url     : this.href,
            method  : 'get',
            success : function(data){
                $('#folio-container').html($(data).filter('#container'));
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off using the load method http://api.jquery.com/load/ , read the section "Loading Page Fragments"

not sure but try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    /* Ajax load in portfolio pages */
    $('#ajax-loader').hide();

    $('div.wp-pagenavi a', 'div#content').click(function(e) {
        $.load(this.href + ' #folio-container');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```